# Undefined symbols for architecture armv7 on Square Reader SDK

Tags: objective-c, xcode, square

I am trying to add Square Reader SDK to the project. The valid architectures are arm64, armv7, armv7s, armv6 and x86. I can run the application on the simulators and physical devices, but when i try to archive the project i am facing with this error:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture armv7:
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_SQRDCheckoutParameters", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in PaymentMethodsViewController-817472c7033dfbe61688dbd48500041c161a14c9d0f9a59a4ed634edaa3b0f80.o
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_SQRDCheckoutController", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in PaymentMethodsViewController-817472c7033dfbe61688dbd48500041c161a14c9d0f9a59a4ed634edaa3b0f80.o
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_SQRDReaderSettingsController", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in SettingsViewController.o
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_SQRDMoney", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in PaymentMethodsViewController-817472c7033dfbe61688dbd48500041c161a14c9d0f9a59a4ed634edaa3b0f80.o
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_SQRDReaderSDK", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in Helper.o
      objc-class-ref in AppDelegate.o
      objc-class-ref in SettingsViewController.o
      objc-class-ref in PaymentMethodsViewController-817472c7033dfbe61688dbd48500041c161a14c9d0f9a59a4ed634edaa3b0f80.o
      objc-class-ref in SplashViewController.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture armv7
```

I added libraries in the *Link Binary With Libraries* section of the *Build Phases*.

Answer (score 1):

What worked for me is to set the target (General > Deployment info) to 11.x